# How to have newline between variables?

Tags: newline, tasker

In a text field in tasker, I want to put two variables with a newline between them:

```
%var1\n%var2
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the field:

```
%var1
%var2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of my Tasker variables support HTML format. It's optional. You need to tick the checkbox to enable HTML format for such variables. After that, just use `<br>` to insert a line break